# Load jQuery plugin with custom jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have custom jQuery:

```
jQueryCustom = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

I have a plugin in separate file:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    // ......
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

What's the best way to pass my jQueryCustom as jQuery to plugin?

I think it's not a good idea to edit library file with plugin.

P.S. I want to load custom jQuery and plugin for it into page, that already **may** has jQuery of another version and this plugin of another version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to edit jQuery variable name in upper closure of plugins for custom jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- load newest version of jQuery (1.7.2) -->
<script src="http://example.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery_1_7_2 = $.noConflict(true);</script>

<!-- load custom version of jQuery (1.1.3) -->
<script src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);</script>

<!-- load your plugin -->
<script src="http://example.com/yourplugin.js"></script>

<script>
/* do something with the newest version of jQuery */
jQuery_1_7_2('#selector').function(); 

/* run your plugin using the custom version of jQuery */
jQuery_1_1_3('#selector').pluginFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: I can't load non-custom jQuery in noConflict mode because it's already may be on page.